# How to merge two maven webapps into one project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, merge

A bit of a back story:

I created a project using Maven,Spring. I sent the code to someone. That someone edited my code from earlier back and sent me the code and told me to merge the code.

So I have two Maven projects. Both are very similar with subtle differences, but there are probably 30-40 java files with hundreds of lines of code. I doubt the most efficient way is to go through each files and check the differences with a human eye.

So my question is - does Eclipse or Maven or anything have an easy way to just merge these two similar projects with subtle difference into one project by itself?

Comment: Are you using source control?  Can you utilize `git merge`?

Comment: @ck1 There is an SVN repository set up but for whatever reason they don't use it. Last version was probably two months ago

Answer (score 1):

Use a diff tool, like Meld or Kdiff.

You can compare folders, show only different files, and easily merge them there

Comment: Do you still have to copy and paste by hand/.

Comment: @bmarkham No, it has a visual diff, side by side, you can click an arrow to copy chosen different part to the other file.

Comment: @bmarkham Also, make sure you check to show only different files, since you say there are subtle differences only.